# Использование библиотеки intel pin

Tags: dll, visual-studio-code, intel, x86

**ОС Windows 7 64bit

IDE VS 2010 C++**

Пытаюсь запустить любой пример из библиотеки `intelpin` но никак не выходит
пытался собрать библиотеку средствами

Командная Строка `VS2010` выдает:

> C:\Pin\source\tools\SimpleExamples>make opodemix.dll
>    MAKE Version
>   5.4  Copyright (c) 1987, 2009 CodeGear
>   Error makefile 9: Command syntax error
>    Error makefile 11: Command syntax error
>   Error makefile 13: Command syntax error
>   Error makefile 14: Command syntax error
>     Error makefile 15: Command syntax error
>   Error makefile 16: Command syntax error
>   *** 6 errors during make ***

Также используя команду `make all`

> C:\Pin\source\tools\SimpleExamples>make all
>  MAKE Version 5.4 
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 2009 CodeGear
>  Error makefile 9: Command syntax
>   error
>  Error makefile 11: Command syntax error
>  Error makefile
>   13: Command syntax error
>  Error makefile 14: Command syntax
>   error
>  Error makefile 15: Command syntax error
>  Error makefile
>   16: Command syntax error
>   *** 6 errors during make ***

Эта беда для двух версий `pin` 
для `pin-2.14-71313-msvc10-windows`
и для pin-3.2-81205-msvc-windows`

Существующие проекты также не дает собрать если просто открывать студией
 [в блоге](https://gist.github.com/extremecoders-re/31fc3dd702ae41096f0c)
нашел как создать проект с руки, какие библиотеки необходимы и какие сделать настойки, сделав все как там указано компилятор ругается:

> Ошибка    1   error LNK1181: не удается открыть входной файл
>   "libxed.lib"  D:\1\SamplePintools\SamplePintools\LINK SamplePintools

хотя данный файл существует и путь к нему прописан
Директрия проекта `D:\1\SamplePinTool`
библиотека распологается 
`C:\Pin`

Проблема решена добавлением пути к библиотеке c:\Pin\extras\xed-ia32\lib\
до этого было добавлено c:\Pin\extras\xed-ia32\lib, тоесть последний слеш важен

Comment: нашел в чем проблема, проблема была решена добавлением папки следующим образом c:\Pin\extras\xed-ia32\lib\ до этого добавлял без последнего слеша то есть так c:\Pin\extras\xed-ia32\lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена добавлением пути к библиотеке со слешем в конце строки
 c:\Pin\extras\xed-ia32\lib\
 
до этого было добавлено 
 c:\Pin\extras\xed-ia32\lib
 тоесть последний слеш важен
 
вопрос с компиляцией make all остается открытым